# I cant control my rplidar(can't stop)

Tags: ros, rplidar, 2dlaserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, everyone
I have a question for you.
my environment is Raspberry pi 3, Ubuntu mate 16.04 LTS, rplidar A2.
I just follow rplidar tutorial(http://wiki.ros.org/rplidar)

everything is ok, but when i killed rplidar(press Ctrl+C),
terminal show me : shutting down processing monitor complete
BUT, lidar continues to work(spining), How can i stop rplidar ?

Do i have to do extra work? or something i forgot?
Please answer me how to solve the problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267717/i-cant-control-my-rplidar(can%27t-stop)/) by [Kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/31029/kang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-07-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2017-07-31**:
Not very familiar with rplidar, but shouldn't it always spin while powered? By killing a node you are basically killing the driver only.

**Comment by [naveedhd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26074/naveedhd/) on 2017-08-02**:
the RPLidar A2 driver (should) starts and stops the motor on launch and exit respectively.

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2017-08-09**:
can you share the source of that information?

**Comment by [naveedhd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26074/naveedhd/) on 2017-08-09**:
In official node [here](https://github.com/robopeak/rplidar_ros/blob/master/src/node.cpp#L315) and nodelet's implementation [here](https://github.com/yujinrobot/rplidar_extras/blob/devel/include/rplidar_extras/rplidar_nodelet.hpp#L53)

**Comment by [Kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/31029/kang/) on 2017-08-30**:
I dont have any idea about how kill a node. can you show me command?

**Comment by [Kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/31029/kang/) on 2017-08-30**:
@naveedhd  i just know when i stoped RPLidar, just press Ctrl+C, i don't know how kill respective node.

**Comment by [Kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/31029/kang/) on 2017-08-30**:
@naveedhd I appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did 2 solutions about my problem.

1. Power problem

- it looks power problem about my rplidar.
- i used 5V/1A power connect. but when i see CPU monitor, i think it was lack about using RPlidar
- so i connect power-supplied USB 3.0 hub with RPlidar.

2. add 2 lines of command

- when i use rplidar i always insert 2 lines of command
  $ source /home/{user}/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
   $ source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash

with 2 solutions, i can start , stop my rplidar.

---

Originally posted by [Kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/31029/kang/) with karma: 16 on 2017-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0